# My Port 81 on IIS does not work when connected from the private static IP

Tags: iis, port

Please help me with this.

I'm trying to connect to IIS on port 81 and 8080 to work on windows azure from my windows phone device.

My when I type 127.0.0.1 it works
when i type 192.168.1.50 it works
when I try 127.0.0.1:81 it works
when i type 192.168.1.50:81 it DOESNOT work.

My firewall is off. Please help me whats wrong. I'm sorry I'm bad at IT.

Thank you.

Comment: Is IIS configured to All IP Addresses?

Comment: In IIS Management, check the properties for the Site - not the virtual directory - it will tell you which IP addresses it is bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the dev fabric address outside of your machine unless you use some kind of a proxy.  I think there are a couple of open source ones out there, I can't remember the name off the top of my head.  That approach seemed too cumbersome to me so I solved this by publishing my app locally to my IIS for local testing and not running the dev fabric.  Of course if your app relies on storage or sql azure then you would need to set those up to run in azure instead of the dev fabric.  I do all of my dev testing against storage that is set up in the cloud instead of my local dev fabric.

Comment: So there's no way out other than the proxy?

Comment: Not that I know of and I dealt with this for some time before I decided to run my web app from IIS.

This is an example of one of the port forwarding solutions that to me seemed like it would be a pain in the neck, mostly because It's yet another thing that could go wrong.

http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/how-remotely-access-windows